# Elasticsearch Multiple Prefix Keywords

Tags: elasticsearch

I need to use the `prefix` filter, but allow multiple different prefixes, i.e.

```
{"prefix": {"myColumn": ["This", "orThis", "orEvenThis"]}}
```

This does not work. And if I add each as a separate `prefix` is also obviously doesn't work.

Help is appreciated.

**Update**

I tried `should` but without any luck:

```
$this->dsl['body']['query']['bool']['should'] = [
    ["prefix" => ["myColumn" =>  "This"]],
    ["prefix" => ["myColumn" =>  "orThis"]]
];
```

When I add those two constraints, I get ALL responses (as though filter is not working). But if I use `must` with either of those clauses, then I do get a response back with the correct prefix.

Comment: And what if you use a `bool` query with `should` statements that each will contain a `prefix` filter?

Comment: @AndreiStefan, that didn't work. I'll update my question to reflect what I did.

Comment: What version are you using?

Comment: @pickypg, I'm using version 2.3.3

Comment: Weird. That should work. Ignoring PHP, what happens if you send the raw request (via Sense or curl)? `curl -XGET localhost:9200/index/_search -d '{ "query" : { "should" : [ { "prefix" : { "myColumn" : "This" } }, { "prefix" : { "myColumn" : "orThis" } } ] } }'`

Comment: @pickypg, I already have other `must` clauses here, but on different fields. Would that case a problem?

Comment: Only in the sense that you need to properly format it. `should` is a companion to `must`. I'd strongly suggest trying outside of PHP to see what's happening, then translate it to the PHP code. Can you show the full with-`must` query?

Comment: @pickypg I can't run a curl command because this is running within a PHP application and I my box does not have the permissions to make the call... My `must` command filters other fields, and `should` command is to filter others. Both are within the `bool` query. I tried to play with `minimum_should_match` to 1 and that made no difference.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/116520/discussion-between-pickypg-and-kousha).

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Based on your comments, it sounds like it may just be an issue with the syntax. With all ES queries (just like SQL ones), I suggest starting simple and just submitting them to ES as the raw DSL outside of code (although in your case this wasn't easily doable). For the request, it's a pretty straight forward one:

```
{
  "query" : {
    "bool" : {
      "must" : [ ... ],
      "filter" : [
        {
          "bool" : {
            "should" : [
              {
                "prefix" : {
                  "myColumn" : "This"
                }
              },
              {
                "prefix" : {
                  "myColumn" : "orThis"
                }
              },
              {
                "prefix" : {
                  "myColumn" : "orEvenThis"
                }
              }
            ]
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  }
}
```

I added it as a `filter` because the optional nature of your prefixing is not improving relevancy: it's literally asking that one of them must match. In such cases where the question is "does this match? yes / no", then you should use a filter (with the added bonus that that's cacheable!). If you're asking "does this match, and which matches better?" then you want a query (because that's *relevancy* / scoring).

Note: The initial issue appeared to be that the `bool` / `must` was unmentioned and the suggestion was to just use a `bool` / `should`.

```
{
  "bool" : {
    "should" : [
      {
        "prefix" : {
          "myColumn" : "This"
        }
      },
      {
        "prefix" : {
          "myColumn" : "orThis"
        }
      },
      {
        "prefix" : {
          "myColumn" : "orEvenThis"
        }
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

behaves differently than

```
{
  "bool" : {
    "must" : [ ... ],
    "should" : [
      {
        "prefix" : {
          "myColumn" : "This"
        }
      },
      {
        "prefix" : {
          "myColumn" : "orThis"
        }
      },
      {
        "prefix" : {
          "myColumn" : "orEvenThis"
        }
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

because the `must` impacts the required nature of `should`. *Without* `must`, `should` behaves like a boolean `OR`. However, with `must`, it behaves as a *completely* optional function to improve relevancy (score). To make it go back to the boolean `OR` behavior *with* `must`, you must add `minimum_should_match` to the `bool` compound query.

```
{
  "bool" : {
    "must" : [ ... ],
    "should" : [
      {
        "prefix" : {
          "myColumn" : "This"
        }
      },
      {
        "prefix" : {
          "myColumn" : "orThis"
        }
      },
      {
        "prefix" : {
          "myColumn" : "orEvenThis"
        }
      }
    ],
    "minimum_should_match" : 1
  }
}
```

Notice that it's a component of the `bool` query, and not of either `should` or `must`!